# Outlook 2007 VBA Address Lists

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007

I am trying to set the reply-to address of outbound emails based on whether a particular address is in the "To" or "CC" field of the outbound message.  I have gotten this far, only to stumble on "Object required" errors on the "Set myCounter..." line.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim oMyItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim i As Integer
Dim AddressEntry As AddressEntry
Dim myCounter As Integer
Set oMyItem = Item
Set myCounter = oMyItem.Recipients.Count

For i = 1 To myCounter
    Set AddressEntry = oMyItem.Recipients(i).AddressEntry
    If (AddressEntry = "someuser@someaddress") Then
        oMyItem.ReplyRecipients.Add "replytouser@someaddress"
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you check (with debugger) that both `oMyItem` and `oMyItem.Recipients` are not null (nothing)?

Comment: Yes, I've actually gotten past that (right when your reply showed up), and now have a separate issue that I can resolve easily enough.  For those that were interested, I deleted the line declaring myCounter and changed the for loop to: For i = 1 To oMyItem.Recipients.Count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is on

```
Set myCounter = oMyItem.Recipients.Count
```

because VB uses `Set` to assign an object (a class), while you're getting an integer!
So you could change it into

```
Dim myCounter As Integer

myCounter = oMyItem.Recipients.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

`myCounter` has been declared as an Integer so there is no need for the `Set`.

Replace

```
Set myCounter = oMyItem.Recipients.Count
```

with

```
myCounter = oMyItem.Recipients.Count
```